# hi, is there a way to get pdf document thru apollo2angular and graphql?

Tags: graphql, apollo-server

following is the response info:

> "%PDF-1.4\n%����\n2 0 obj\n<>stream\nx��X�s�F\u0010�\u0019����$\u0010JaF\u000f\t\t�*:Iw�:�h������-ڀg/}]�yk��Z\u0002��0Vڈ��&��\n��ɐֳ�L\u0012?�4\u000bi���\u001b�D\u0017\tPقYl���\u0019p\u0010:\-g���Oǜ�F�\u0019�L�&�_c6�'\u0016��cv���fhm�ҏ?;�ǴK�U��d\u0007�!����qG{,k�M��\u001e۬�)-�E�GU¢\u0019�\u0003(�����q2R�\u001c%K�vC���[�;�j\u0004�E�PO�hH��dk\u0011\fN����騈���\u000fs=8���9\u001fY�\u00185t\u001d��A0Sa��!\u000e��i\u000f�(1R�q����>�\u0017�i��\u0017<�$��\u0015�;�|/^�;���v̺H\u0019�1�\t�@��m�?�\u00137q�\u0004�\\u0010ְ'M鴨\u000b���0�9B1�ێ���=�K,Z\"'���\u0019���3��W\u0010q\u0000A�D��� �Hh���\u0017�c�k��̉�i�W\u000b�M`ph�P�#��0W:ʥ\u0003�*ӕ�9���\u0015OG��\u000e�$A)>�\u0018H*�R�1 7��~ch\u001a�CUfQ�j�9��+��K��Џ�\u001a{�G��)\f�D\u0012\f���(C\u0005��?ݗ��m�������c��0Ϩ�v@*@Hp�\u0019�Y�!��7�-�\u001b�a�w�3��&�T0q=�K�-ؚ�\u0018`\u000e�)���]N�P\u0019ZB.�$w\u0015�\u0006n�&6|

Answer (score 0):

Hey yes there is but it takes a little custom work!

Here is how you can do it to work with [scaphold.io](https://scaphold.io) but you could extend this to your own implementation as well!

Basically what is happening is you attach the file at the root level of a multipart/form-data request and then from the input in your GraphQL variables you point to the key of the file in the request. Here is some code to show how you can retrofit and ApolloClient instance with a file-ready network interface that you can then feed into Angular2Apollo.

```
import { createNetworkInterface } from 'apollo-client';

// Create a file-ready ApolloClient instance.
export function makeClientApolloFileHandler() {
  const graphqlUrl = `https://scaphold.io/graphql/my-app`;
  const networkInterface = createNetworkInterface(graphqlUrl);
  networkInterface.query = (request) => {
    const formData = new FormData();

    // Parse out the file and append at root level of form data.
    const varDefs = request.query.definitions[0].variableDefinitions;
    let vars = [];
    if (varDefs && varDefs.length) {
      vars = varDefs.map(def => def.variable.name.value);
    }
    const activeVars = vars.map(v => request.variables[v]);
    const fname = find(activeVars, 'blobFieldName');
    if (fname) {
      const blobFieldName = fname.blobFieldName;
      formData.append(blobFieldName, request.variables[blobFieldName]);
    }

    formData.append('query', printGraphQL(request.query));
    formData.append('variables', JSON.stringify(request.variables || {}));
    formData.append('operationName', JSON.stringify(request.operationName || ''));

    const headers = { Accept: '*/*' };
    if (localStorage.getItem('scaphold_user_token')) {
      headers.Authorization = `Bearer ${localStorage.getItem('scaphold_user_token')}`;
    }

    return fetch(graphqlUrl, {
      headers,
      body: formData,
      method: 'POST',
    }).then(result => result.json());
  };

  const clientFileGraphql = new ApolloClient({
    networkInterface,
    initialState: {},
  });
  return clientFileGraphql;
}
```

After this function does its work on the request you might have FormData that looks like this (if it were encoded in JSON):

```
{
  "query": "mutation CreateFile($input:CreateFileInput) { createFile(input: $input) { ... }",
  "variables": {
    "input": {
      "blobFieldName": "myFile",
      "name": "MyFileName!"
    }
  },
  // Note how the blobFieldName points to this key
  "myFile": <Buffer of file data in multipart/form-data>
}
```

The server would then need to understand how to interpret this in order to look for the file in the payload and associate it with the correct object etc.

Hope this helps!